# Syntax errors when fields are added

Tags: select, ssms, average

The following code worked well for averaging

```
 select
 [state], areatype, area, '00' [period], indcode, ownership, 
 avg(sites) sites, avg(employment) employment
 from dbo.tablename
 group by [state], areatype, area, indcode, ownership;
```

I kept it short and simple so to learn the concept. I add two more fields to the second and fifth lines and now getting syntax errors. Any insight to offer?

```
 select
 [state], areatype, area, periodyear, '00' [period], indcodetype, indcode, ownership, 
 avg(sites) sites, avg(employment) employment
 from dbo.tablename
 group by [state], areatype, area, periodyear, incodetype, indcode, ownership;

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'sites'.
```

Comment: Please share the error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

For reasons that I can't explain, I am adding one element at a time and it is working. If I type it all out, I get the syntax errors but If I start with what worked and add one item at a time and execute, it works.